# Bxslider not appearing in tab

Tags: jquery, css, bxslider

I have accordion tabs on my website and I am trying to use bxslider within them for my slides. The issue is that when the slides open up it shows the slider as having a height of 0.

I have tried using the reload function given by bxslider but it keeps telling me it is not a function - I may be doing something wrong.

I have also tried to add a static height to the viewport but that just messes up the images. I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dLk825bg/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        auto: 'true',
        pager: 'false',
    });

    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function (){
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
        //Hide the other panels
        $('#accordion section').not($(this).parent()).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

*Note: I manually copy pasted the scripts and CSS for bxslider into the JSFiddle because I was unable to figure out how to add them without doing so. My script can be found below the bxslider script*

Comment: For future references, you can load scripts and CSS by copy-pasting their links in the **External Resources** on the left of the JSFiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is resolved by using the [`redrawSlider()`](https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4) method. It is specifically for when bxSlider is unhidden. It requires a repaint. This is only documented [here](https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4). Unfortunately, it's usage seems inaccurate, so I came up with something that actually works very well.

I placed anchors inside each of the `.accordion-toggle` and delegated a click event on the anchors. Originally, I tried to place the method within the accordion's function, but it wasn't working. The `redrawSlider()` wasn't working at first and after a little research I found nothing...so I guessed that it must be the timing, **BINGO!**

Btw, I know it isn't documented, but if you have multiple sliders, each one must be uniquely referenced. So even if your sliders share a common class, add a unique class for each of them or an id is good also. Each slider should have it's own setup even if they are identical.

Also, Booleans are not Strings, and sometimes JavaScript auto type conversion doesn't always catch it. So be mindful when using true and false values and leave them ***unquoted***. If quoted, it is technically a String.

```
$('a.trig1').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function() {
      bx1.redrawSlider();
    }, 0);
});

$('a.trig2').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function() {
      bx2.redrawSlider();
    }, 0);
});
```

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hidden bxSliders</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css">
  <style>
    #accordion section .accordion-content {
      display: none;
      padding: 0 30px 30px 30px;
    }
    #accordion section.active .accordion-content {
      display: block;
    }
    .bx img {
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="accordion">
    <section>
      <h2 class="accordion-toggle"><a href="#" class="trig1">Test 1</a></h2>
      <div class="accordion-content">
        <p>slider 1</p>
        <ul class="bxslider1 bx">
          <li>
            <img src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/640x360/p02scs5q.jpg">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://d2v9y0dukr6mq2.cloudfront.net/video/thumbnail/EhSddnV/black-and-white-tunnel-effect-turning-left-zoomed-video-background-for-a-transition-or-luma-key-spinning-left-tunnel-effect-zoomed-tunnel-hole-visual-effect_41rgnb8w__M0000.jpg">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/541094548_640x360.jpg">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2 class="accordion-toggle"><a href="#" class="trig2">Test 2</a></h2>
      <div class="accordion-content">
        <p>slider 2</p>
        <ul class="bxslider2 bx">
          <li>
            <img src="http://cache1.asset-cache.net/xd/513331420.jpg?v=1&c=IWSAsset&k=2&d=2DF30557A92EF68A79FB2FAE5DFF30DA4E7679DD01108BC64BBAD824103B0C3B9D10438B022685F4">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="http://www.rantsports.com/clubhouse/files/2015/03/Arianny-Celeste-7.jpg">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="http://breakingenergy.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2013/04/72410727.jpg">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.3/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    var bx1 = $('.bxslider1').bxSlider({
      auto: true,
      pause: 2000,
      autoHover: true,
      pager: false
    });

    var bx2 = $('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
      auto: true,
      pause: 2000,
      autoHover: true,
      pager: false
    });

    $('a.trig1').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      setTimeout(function() {
        bx1.redrawSlider();
      }, 0);
    });

    $('a.trig2').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      setTimeout(function() {
        bx2.redrawSlider();
      }, 0);
    });


    $('.accordion-toggle').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
      $('#accordion section').not($(this).parent()).removeClass('active');
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not really sure why you added an anchor element, adding a class to the h2 works just fine for this, I tweaked it a bit to fit my other scripts but works like a charm, thanks a bunch! A bit silly that the reload function can't target more than one slider of the same class but oh well. Cheers

Comment: Originally I tried combining functions under the `<h2>` which didn't work. I didn't bother to remove the anchors because at the time I got it working perfectly so I lifted my hands from the keyboard before I get jinxed and screw it up. You are welcome, sir. Yeah, it kinda defeats the purpose of class.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [comment](https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/issues/289#issuecomment-40008319),

> the bxSlider interface is only available on jQuery selectors that match a
>   single element

Using his [example](http://jsfiddle.net/G8Laq/27/), I came up with this solution.

```
$(function() {
  var bxConfig = {
    auto: 'true',
    pager: 'false'
  };

  // cache elements that we will be re-using
  var $accordion = $('#accordion'), 
      $sections = $accordion.find('section'),
      $sliders = [];

  // initialize sliders
  $('.bxslider').each(function (i) {
      $sliders[i] = $(this).bxSlider(bxConfig);
  });

  $accordion.find('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function() {
    var $current = $(this).closest('section');  
    // close other sections
    $sections.not($current).removeClass('active');
    // toggle current section
    $current.toggleClass('active');
    // check if section is active
    if ($current.hasClass('active')) {
      // get the position of the current section among his siblings
      var index = $sections.index($current);
      // reload slider at the given position
      $sliders[index].reloadSlider();
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyjOLJ?editors=0110) I shrunk the images just to make it easier to see.

I am using the index of the section to determine which slider to reload. Therefore, this solution will not work if you have 2 or more sliders within each section OR if not all sections have sliders.  Another way is to loop through **all** sliders and reload them whenever you open a section -- but that's wasteful.

Comment: This works - but in my case I have more than one slider in certain sections so this doesn't work like you said, it also breaks a localStorage script I am using to determine active tabs on page back. Thanks though! :)